# Unable to return an optional as an optional

Tags: swift, function, option-type

Why can't I get Swift to return a value as an optional.

I have a funtion that checks if an optional contains a value and return it as an optional if it isn't:

```
var someOptional: String?

func checkIfOptional<T>(value: T?) -> (String, T) {
    if let _value = value {
        return (("Your optional contains a value. It is: \(_value)"), (_value))
    } else {
        return (("Your optional did not contain a value"), (value?)) //ERROR: Value of optional type 'T?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    }
}
```

When the optional is nil. Ist should return the same optional the was given to the function.
If there is a value. It should return the unwrapped value.

Comment: Try to use this one: -> (String, T)?

Comment: I don't want to return an optional Tuple.

Comment: *What* do you want to return if the value is nil?

Comment: The Optional that was passed in.

Comment: Then change the return type to `(String, T?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to declare an `enum` like this:

```
enum Value<T> {
    case full(String, T)
    case empty(String, T?)
}

func checkIfOptional<T>(_ value: T?) -> Value<T> {
    if let _value = value {
        return .full("Your optional contains a value. It is: \(_value)", _value)
    } else {
        return .empty("Your optional did not contain a value.", value)
    }
}

var toto: String?

print(checkIfOptional(toto))   // empty("Your optional did not contain a value", nil)
print(checkIfOptional("Blah")) // full("Your optional contains a value. It is: Blah", "Blah")
```

To treat a `Value` you should use `switch` this way:

```
var toto: String?

let empty = checkIfOptional(toto)
let full = checkIfOptional("Blah")

func treatValue<T>(_ value: Value<T>) {
    switch(value) {
        case .full(let msg, let val):
            print(msg)
            print(val)
        case .empty(let msg, _):
            print(msg)
    }
}

treatValue(empty) // Your optional did not contain a value.
treatValue(full)  // Your optional contains a value. It is: Blah\nBlah
```

But all of this seems to me to only add needless complexity to the straightforward type that is `Optional`. So you might want to expand on what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am really just playing around with optionals. Thank you for the thorough solution

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return an optional you have to declare the return type as optional

```
func checkIfOptional<T>(value: T?) -> (String, T?) {
    if let _value = value {
        return ("Your optional contains a value. It is: \(_value)", value)
    } else {
        return ("Your optional did not contain a value", value)
        // or even  return ("Your optional did not contain a value", nil)
}
```

I removed all unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: But if it return an optional or not depends on whether there was a value or not.

Comment: If `let _value = value` fails it is `nil`. As the literal string implies *there is no value*. If it returns a value it is optional.

Comment: @Marmelador You don’t seem to unterstand the concept of an optional. If you are not sure whether there will be a value or not, exactly like you are with the return of your function, you must use an optional.